# Finding length of some sides on a triangle construction.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I must find the length of $DE$ and $EC$

Pythagoras told me the length of $AB$, and I know that the right angles give me similar triangles, but I don't know how to proceed.

[image]

Also tried Pythagoras on the triangle $DEC$ but got nothing.

Some hint or help is very welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned Pythagoras gives us that $AB=15$, then use the similarity of triangles:

$\frac{DE}{DC}=\frac{AB}{AC} \rightarrow DE=\frac{15 \cdot 15}{20}=11.25$

Now, use Pythagoras to find $EC$ and then $AE=AC-EC$